# Azure Data Factoryy connectivity

Tags: azure

Is there a way to restrict Azure Data Factory to be only accessible through Azure bastion host? To elaborate, I want anyone reaching the ADF URL to go through a Browser running in an azure bastion host?

Answer (score 0):

As per the current  [Azure Security Baseline for data factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/benchmark/azure/baselines/data-factory-security-baseline?toc=/azure/data-factory/TOC.json#privileged-access)  Documentation, it is suggested to Use privileged access workstations for Secured, isolated workstations are critical for the security of sensitive roles like administrators, developers, and critical service operators. Use highly secured user workstations and Azure Bastion for administrative tasks.

Use Azure AD, Microsoft Defender ATP, or Microsoft Intune to deploy a secure and managed user workstation for administrative tasks. You can centrally manage secured workstations to enforce a security configuration that includes:

- Strong authentication
- Software and hardware baselines
- Restricted logical and network access